# TCServer 3 versus 2 - Classloading issues

Tags: tomcat, aop, tcserver

We've run our applications on TCServer 2.9 for around 5 years now. We recently decided to migrate to TCServer 3.1.2 (Tomcat 8). However, the very same application that worked in 2.9 stopped working in 3.1.2.

There are two apps, the first one, a Spring app that uses Aspectj (aop.xml under META-INF) and the second one that fails with a hibernate is an AbstractMethod error.

To resolve the aop.xml issue, I had to have a reference to the /classes/META-INF aop.xml by settng the server.common variable.

The second application I'm still trying to sort out, with no clue where to begin.

So in essence, the classloading behaviour between versions has changed. If I run a pure Apache Tomcat 8 instance, both applications work out the box.

Comment: What exact version of Apache Tomcat 8.0 did you test with? You shouldn't have an issue with tc Runtime 8 if it worked with Apache Tomcat 8.

We would like to understand more about the problem you are having with tc Server. Could you post the errors you are getting? Also do you have a sample app you can point us to that we could test in our environment that might show us the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: apache-tomcat-8.0.21.

Comment: apache-tomcat-8.0.21. The TCServer is 3.1.2-RELEASE. I'm running a spring aop application with an aop.xml file in the classes/META-INF directory.  This is a standard AOP implementation, maybe if you can try this with a sample application. The error that manifests is that this file isn't picked up, so the subsequent LoadTimeWeaving does not occur. The test would be to write a simple aspectJ web application, and then see if the LTW starts up as expected. I don't have a sample app I could share with you unfortunately, I've searched and can't seem to find one.

Comment: With 3.1.2 we experienced the following: 1. Slow response times 2. Un-returned JDBC connections using tomcat-jdbc. 2. NoClassDef Issues with our hibernate classes.  We then decided to go to 2.9.11 and the problems disappeared immediately. We are going to go with this version in production now.

Comment: Kiren, Please open a support issue, so we can get someone assigned to your case.   
In the meantime, Are you experiencing similar performance issues with Apache Tomcat 8?  If you moved from tc Server 2.9.x (which contained tc Runtime 6 and 7) to tc Server 3.1.2 using tc Runtime 8.  I assume you we using tc Runtime 7 previously?  Did you also upgrade the JVM version when you moved to tc Runtime 8?  Are you using any template when creating your tcServer instances?